# How to pass indexPath.row of the dragged cell into a function? (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Currently, I have a tableview with different "user profile pictures" populating each cell. As you drag the picture past a certain point horizontally, it triggers another function. This is done with UIPanGestureRecogniser.

My problem is, how do I pass the indexPath.row of the dragged image into the function, so the function knows which "user" to work with? Right now it has no way of knowing which cell was dragged.

If someone could outline the general direction of how this can be done I would be very grateful!

Comment: show some code like what you have tried.

Comment: `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` might helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work:

1. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set the `tag` property of your image to the row number.

   ```
   // something like this
   let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
   cell.image.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
   cell.image.tag = indexPath.row
   ```
2. In the handler for the pan:

   ```
   func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
       if let row = recognizer.view?.tag {
           // use row number
           println("row number is \(row)")
       }
   }
   ```